# Is it possible to use jenkins-agent with given ip pattern in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Basically, there are many jenkins-nodes in a jenkins-server. The `launch-method` of the majority is `launch agents via ssh` and the `host` under the `launch method` option is the actual ip. However, the labels of the majority are empty.

The main problem is a firewall in front of my server `10.227.10.10`. In short, this firewall will block the packets. If using the jenkins-pipeline like below, the packets from some jenkins-nodes may get blocked by the firewall.

I read the [pipeline syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/index.html#agent) and the `label` can be the solution. However, there will be massive work to configure the `label` part of the jenkins-nodes. Any ideas?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('stage1') {
            agent any
            //  agent {ip '10.227.*.*'}  // This would be a better solution
            steps {
                sh "curl http://10.227.10.10"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ?"However, there will be massive work to configure the label part of the jenkins-nodes"? Just run a groovy script to set them all... [Add a new label to agents meeting a condition](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Add+a+new+label+to+agents+meeting+a+condition)

Comment: @lan This is a possible solution which use scripts to add an ip as an additional label. After this, is it possible to use regular expression to match some ip(the network-part)? If not, I need to put the network part of the ip as an additional label.

Comment: I presume your nodes have IP addresses as "Host" names?

Comment: @IanW Yes, the majority has the ip address as the host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the IP address is available as a property of the [Slave](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Slave.html#getComputer--) or via [getComputer()](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Computer.html)

The [Pipeline Agent](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/index.html#agent), **label** only supports [explicit labels](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Label.html), but does allow for conditions. You can just make a new label (eg: "`227Net`" ), add it to the nodes using the console groovy script below, then reference that label in your pipeline:

```
agent  { node { label '227Net' } }
```

Should work fine.

```
def newLabel = '227Net'
Jenkins.instance.slaves.findAll {it.name.contains('10.227') }.each {agent -> 
  oldLabelString = agent.getLabelString()
  println "Relabeling ${agent.name} : ${oldLabelString} + ${newLabel}"
  newLabelString = oldLabelString + " " + newLabel
  agent .setLabelString(newLabelString)
}
return
```

Comment: I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068095/get-ssh-slave-node-hostname-ip-in-jenkins-pipeline).  The ip address is avaiable in the [`hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.getHost()`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/ssh-slaves/hudson/plugins/sshslaves/SSHLauncher.html), isnt it?

Comment: Well, `{node {label '<somevalue>` } } still does not support regex pattern match. `getHost() / getComputer()` returns the hostName, not the IP (if you provided an IP as the hostName, it still returns the hostName.. You have the framework to update the labels; if you want to dig down into `com.trilead.ssh2.Connection` to parse the IP address to determine what nodes to apply the apply to, seems like a lot of work (and the connections have to be established). You still have to assign a fixed `{ label }`. Please publish s sol'n if you get one.